# Isn't Nexus open source any more?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I would like to use [Nexus 3.x](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype), but I think it's licensing has changed. 2.x was `EPL v1`, but 3.x has a `SONATYPE MASTER EULA AGREEMENT`, instead.

My question is: Nexus 3.x can be used freely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You also asked this on the User list which I answered yesterday but for posterity:

Here’s the short answer: “Yes”, you can still use Nexus OSS 3.x in production. There were no changes to the state of the licensing intent between 2x and 3x.

We've attempted to simplify the distribution by providing a single download of the bits that can be license activated to enable the paid functionality without requiring a separate installation/upgrade. In the process the licensing was necessarily consolidated as well.

The core OSS download is free and governed by the terms of the EPL license. There are some features like the Repository Health Check which are Free but not open sourced (in 2x you'd see the "Free Binary License" that describes this).

I'll work with our GC and Product Team to make this more clear in subsequent releases.

Brian Fox, CTO, Sonatype

Comment: Would it be possible to add a link to where this document is on your website? There isn't a link to the license and the license isn't displayed on the page for Nexus 3.x OSS. Some companies require that the licensing information be readily accessible for auditing purposes.

Comment: "in terms of the EPL license", but which version? There is a blog post stating 1.0 from 2012, is this still the case?

Comment: Nexus OSS is EPL version 1